# Coin Change Algorithm C

Tags: c, algorithm, coin-change

I'm having some trouble coming up with a working algorithm for the following problem.

Given determined quantities of available coins from 100, 50, 25 and 10 cents, I need to find how to fit a combination of these coins into a given value x. (it doesn't have to be optimal, any combination from availables coins will do).

So far, I've got this code, which works only for some cases.

```
struct coins{
    int valor;
    int quant;
};

int change = 0;
int changecoins[4] = {0};
struct coins available_coins[4] = { 0 };

moedas_disp[3].value = 10; //10 cents coins
moedas_disp[2].value = 25; //25 cents coins
moedas_disp[1].value = 50;  //50 cents coins
moedas_disp[0].value = 100; //100 cents coins

//quantity values just for test purposes
moedas_disp[3].quant = 10; //10 cents coins
moedas_disp[2].quant = 15; //25 cents coins
moedas_disp[1].quant = 8;  //50 cents coins
moedas_disp[0].quant = 12; //100 cents coins


for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    while((change/available_coins[i].value>0)&&(available_coins[i].quant>0)){
        change -= available_coins[i].value;
        available_coins[i].quant--;
        changecoins[i]++;
    }
}
if(change>0){
    printf("It was not possible to change the value");
}
else{
    printf("Change:\n");
    printf("\t%d 100 cent coin(s).\n", changecoins[0]);
    printf("\t%d 50 cent coin(s).\n", changecoins[1]);
    printf("\t%d 25 cent coin(s).\n", changecoins[2]);
    printf("\t%d 10 cent coin(s).\n", changecoins[3]);
}
```

However for quantities like 30 this won't work. The program will fit 1 coin of 25 cents, but then have 5 cents left, which will fail to compute. This also occurs with 40, 65, and so on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code and see where it's not working as you intend.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. 
With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. 
This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I don't think it is some line in particular that is wrong, but rather the algorithm logic. And I can't come up with a logic that works 100% of the cases. (I've been trying for a long time)

Comment: As we've said, use a debugger to step through the code and see where it's not working as you intend. A debugger works for you just like it would work for us, and it's an excellent learning opportunity. It's never too early to learn to use a debugger, which is one of the most powerful tools a developer has in their toolbox. As far as the logic, grab a piece of paper and pencil and work it through. How do you do it there?

Comment: A good solution to the problem will also handle the cases where change cannot be made for the input value (e.g. 15 cents). Also, observe that any value that can be made using 100-cent coins or 50-cent coins can be made using 10-cent coins. So it will be helpful to consider the simpler case of making change from 10-cent coins and 25-cent coins only. The optimizations can come later.

Comment: This is a common enough example of [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) that it gets its own [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem).

Comment: Does it have to be iterative or it can be recursive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a recursive algorithm along the following steps:

- Take 1 100c coin and try to break down the remaining amount into only 50, 25, 10s
- If that didn't work, take 2 100c coins and try to break down the remaining amount into only 50, 25, 10s
- Etc.

If you tried every possibility for the number of 100c coins (including 0!) then you will have covered all possible solutions.

I wrote some demo code. If this is homework then please don't copy-paste my code but maybe write your own code once you understand the ideas involved ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool coin_find(unsigned int total, unsigned int *denom)
{
    if ( total == 0 )
        return true;    // Success - reduced total remaining to 0

    if ( *denom == 0 )
        return false;   // Failure - tried all coins in the list with no solution yet

    // Try 0 of the largest coin, then 1, etc.
    for (unsigned int d = 0; ; ++d)
    {
        if ( d * *denom > total )
            return false;

        if ( coin_find(total - d * *denom, denom + 1) )
        {
            if ( d ) 
                printf("%ux%uc ", d, *denom);
            return true;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if ( argc < 2 )
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    unsigned int denoms[] = { 100, 50, 25, 10, 0 };

    long t = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    if ( t < 0 || t >= LONG_MAX )
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    if ( !coin_find(t, denoms) )
        printf("No solution found");

    printf("\n");
}
```

Exercises for the reader:

1. Loop backwards instead of forwards so that we find tidier solutions by default.
2. Output only the breakdown with the smallest number of coins.
3. Output all possible breakdowns.

Bonus exercise:

- Rewrite this to not actually use recursion at all; instead use an array that holds the solution so far, and *backtrack* when you reach the end. Exercise 3 will actually be easier this way.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The following solution uses *Dynamic Programming* and you can use it as long as the value of `M` (`x` for you) is small. If `prev[j]` is different than `-1` then this means that `j` can be made with the given coins. `coin[j]` store the value of the coin used to make `j`, and `prev[j]` is the value without using `coin[j]`. Thus, `(j - prev[j]) / coin[j]` give us the number of coins of denomination `coin[j]` used to make weight `j`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int
    COINS = 4;

int M = 1100; 
int prev[10000];
int coin[10000];
// Available denominations.
int value[COINS] = { 10, 25, 50, 100 };
// Available quantities.
int quant[COINS] = { 10, 15, 8, 12 };
// Number of selected coins per denomination.
int answer[COINS] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };

int main() {
    // base case    
    prev[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
        prev[i] = -1;

    // dynamic programming
    for (int i = 0; i < COINS; i++)
        for (int j = M; j >= 0; j--)
            if (prev[j] != -1) {
                int k = 1;
                while (k <= quant[i] && j + k * value[i] <= M) {
                    if (prev[j + k * value[i]] == -1) {
                        prev[j + k * value[i]] = j;
                        coin[j + k * value[i]] = value[i];
                    }
                    k++;
                }
            }

    // build the answer
    if (prev[M] != -1) {
        int current = M;
        while (current > 0) {
            int k = 0;
            while (k < COINS && coin[current] != value[k])
                k++;
            answer[k] += (current - prev[current]) / coin[current];
            current = prev[current];
        }
        printf("Change\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < COINS; i++)
            printf("\t%d %d cent coin(s).\n", answer[i], value[i]);
    } else {
        printf("It was not possible to change the value");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because 25%10 is not equal to 0, You need to consider it. Try this algorithm:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct coins{
    int value;
    int quant;
};

int main()
{
    int change = 30;
    int changecoins[4] = {0};
    struct coins available_coins[4] = { 0 };
    int temp;

    available_coins[3].value = 10; //10 cents coins
    available_coins[2].value = 25; //25 cents coins
    available_coins[1].value = 50;  //50 cents coins
    available_coins[0].value = 100; //100 cents coins

    //quantity values just for test purposes
    available_coins[3].quant = 10; //10 cents coins
    available_coins[2].quant = 15; //25 cents coins
    available_coins[1].quant = 8;  //50 cents coins
    available_coins[0].quant = 12; //100 cents coins


    if(((change/10 < 2)&&(change%10 != 0)) || (change/10 >= 2)&&((change%10 != 5) && change%10 != 0)) {
        printf("It was not possible to change the value\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
            changecoins[i] = change / available_coins[i].value;
            change = change % available_coins[i].value;
            if(changecoins[i] >= available_coins[i].quant) {
                change = change + (changecoins[i] - available_coins[i].quant) * available_coins[i].value;
                changecoins[i] = available_coins[i].quant;
            }
        }

        if(change%10 == 5) {
            if(available_coins[2].quant < 1) {
                printf("It was not possible to change the value\n");
                return 0;
            }
            else {
                changecoins[2] = change / available_coins[2].value;
                change = change % available_coins[2].value;
                if(changecoins[2] >= available_coins[2].quant) {
                    change = change + (changecoins[2] - available_coins[2].quant) * available_coins[2].value;
                    changecoins[2] = available_coins[2].quant;
                }
                if(change%10 == 5) {
                    changecoins[2]--;
                    change = change + available_coins[2].value;
                }
            }
        }

        changecoins[3] = change / available_coins[3].value;
        change = change % available_coins[3].value;
        if(changecoins[3] >= available_coins[3].quant) {
            change = change + (changecoins[3] - available_coins[3].quant) * available_coins[3].value;
            changecoins[3] = available_coins[3].quant;
        }

        if(change>0) {
            printf("It was not possible to change the value\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("Change:\n");
            printf("\t%d 100 cent coin(s).\n", changecoins[0]);
            printf("\t%d 50 cent coin(s).\n", changecoins[1]);
            printf("\t%d 25 cent coin(s).\n", changecoins[2]);
            printf("\t%d 10 cent coin(s).\n", changecoins[3]);

            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                available_coins[i].quant -= changecoins[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```